# Can I use Shared Preference rather SQLite Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I want to keep data with shared preference. I looked some examples on the internet but I couldn't answer my question. I can use database for my purpose but it is really hard especially in android. There are examples that has more than 10 class to just create database. Why is it hard ?. It is cons of the db in android.

Anyway, I will keep just 1 table that has 4(relational) columns in my application.

id | name | surname |phone number.

Can I use Shared Preference to achieve this goal? How to use for 4 different columns?

Comment: No you cant use SharedPrefs for the given scenario.Using DB in android is not that hard, There are plenty of good tutorials available which can help you create simple tables.

Comment: You want to provide an anti-pattern (bad solution to a problem). The fact that you followed a **bad tutorial** on databases, doesn't mean that they are complicated to use. In facts, you can just use 1 class for your database helper. Then, **optionally**, you can provide a class for each object model you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Database for this,
But if you will have only one entry in each column then you can use shared preference

Database is not that hard, check below page
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

DataBase Meet your needs ,if you want to easily  use DataBase ,try xUtils, ------some code about xUtils:

```
//add
User user1 = new User();
user1.setAge(40);
user1.setName("bob");
user1.setPhone("123456789");

ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(user1);

 try {
 MyApplication.dbUtils.saveAll(list);         
 } catch (DbException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.d("TAG",e.getMessage());
 }

 //updata---1
try {
   User  users = MyApplication.dbUtils.findById(User.class,1);
   users.setAge(18);
   MyApplication.dbUtils.update(users,"age");
    } catch (DbException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 //delete
 User user = new User();
 user.setId(3);
 try {
     MyApplication.dbUtils.delete(user);
 } catch (DbException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

//query
List<User> allUsers = MyApplication.dbUtils.findAll(Selector.from(User.class)
.where("age",">","20")
.and("age","<","50"));
```